# What is python alternative to thor (ruby) for command line applications?

Tags: python, thor, command-line-arguments, command-line-interface

What is the python alternative to [Thor](http://whatisthor.com/) for building self-documenting command line utilities?

**UPDATE:** The *click* is the closest equivalent of Thor for python, see http://click.pocoo.org/

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html ?

Comment: The question has been answered. I choose a library --- argparse. I understand the rules, my question could be seen as violation of them, and I do not see a point in putting the question on hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python offers natively (via standard library) two packages to create auto-documenting interfaces for command line tools: [optparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html) and [argparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html).

The docs says that `optparse` is deprecated and `argparse` replaces it, maintaining some backward compatibility where possible. Though, argparse is not so easy to use and 3rd-party libraries have been created.

Have a look at [docopt](https://github.com/docopt/docopt) and the [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pXhcPJK5cMc) about it. [cliff](https://cliff.readthedocs.org/) is another possibility.

To write line-oriented command interpreters you can find useful the Python [cmd](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cmd.html) module.

I finally want to point out that docopt and cliff are not *the* Python alternative/s as you asked, but just the couple I found.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure that this is exactly what you want, but imho it is [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/) + [python docstring](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) + [argparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html).